# strange problem with ToolTip

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLivrareExterna" runat="server" 
 OnCheckedChanged="ChkLivrare_CheckedChanged"
 AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="<%= getChkLivrareExternaToolTip() %>"/>
```

and the method is:

```
 protected String getChkLivrareExternaToolTip()
{
    return "testIN";
}
```

I cannot understand why, at tool tip on mouse over it puts:

> 

instead of evaluating this expression...

Tried with simple quotes but the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is not supported for setting properties on server-side controls.

Instead, you can set the property in your code-behind, in `Page_Load`:

```
chkLivrareExterna.ToolTip = getChkLivrareExternaToolTip();
```

You can also set the property using data-binding syntax:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLivrareExterna" runat="server" 
              OnCheckedChanged="ChkLivrare_CheckedChanged"
              AutoPostBack="true" ToolTip="<%# getChkLivrareExternaToolTip() %>"/>
```

You then need to call `chkLivrareExterna.DataBind()` in `Page_Load`.

Comment: And even it it were, the <%= %> bee stings are short for _Response_.Write() - in other words, direct the output buffer and not your page object.